# Conditional SELECT over month-based records in Hive

Tags: hive, conditional-statements

I have a table containing year data with number of purchases per month per customer. It looks like this:

```
ID  MON     NUM_PURCHASES
1   1       1
2   1       3
3   1       4
2   2       5
```

(where ID is customer id, mon is month in a year). I want to select all IDs which have **at least 1 purchase** per month through the year.

I am looking for more elegant solution than (this does not work - see my edit 2019-04-03):

```
SELECT distinct id
FROM my_table
where (num_purchases >= 1 and mon = 1) and 
(num_purchases >= 1 and mon = 2) and ...
(num_purchases >= 1 and mon = 12);
```

(Note that "..." denotes all counts of mon values from 1 to 12)

What is more elegant way to do it? Thanks.

**EDIT (2019-04-03):**

I realize how ridiculous query above is - it's never going to return anything unless I transform the table and put all the records from one customer in one row :/.

After Vamsi's answer, I realized I did not mention that my table does not contain records with 0 purchases for the month, it only contains data (for a customer) if he made a purchase in a month (so some months are missing).

Thanks to Vamsi's solution, I found workaround as:

```
select id, total_purchases
FROM
(select id, SUM(CAST(mon as int)) as sum_mon, SUM(CAST(num_purchases as int)) as total_purchases
FROM my_table
group by cid) a where sum_mon == 78;
```

(It's far from elegant - again, but at least it works. However, it will not work for more generic cases, i.e. if we have 0 records for each customer in the table, or if we want to select customers who made 2 or more purchases in a month. I do not need this at the moment though, but it could be useful for someone who is running into similar problem.)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `group by` and `having`.

```
SELECT id
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(CAST(num_purchases > 0 AS INT)) = 12
```

Use `year` in `group by` if the table has such a column.

*The solution assumes there is one row per id per month and there are no missing months. If it is not the case, modify the query based on the idea shown*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing months and proposing solution. I realize that I made mistake in my original query and I forgot to mention that indeed my table does not contain all months for a customer. I edited my post accordingly and proposed a workaround based on your solution.